# How can I disable Windows Defender using the command line?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-defender

I am looking for a way to disable Windows Defender on Windows 8/8.1/10 using the command line. Everything I've found so far has involved using a GUI at some point, and this isn't useful for a process I am looking to automate using a script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Moab I did see that one, but I need a way to do it using the command line, preferably without batch files or similar.

Comment: A batch file is nothing more than a bunch commands for the command prompt, the reason you use a batch file is because there is too many commands to do it manually for what you want to do.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do this would be to use PowerShell to disable it, the command you probably want is this:

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
```

For an article on using PowerShell to disable/enable Windows Defender check here: http://wmug.co.uk/wmug/b/pwin/archive/2015/05/12/quickly-disable-windows-defender-on-windows-10-using-powershell

Here is the TechNet article for a more detailed look at available defender cmdlets: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn433280.aspx

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the links. I guess I missed those in my searching.

Comment: @AWarnock Absolutely! Let me know if you need any more information in order to mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: You must use PowerShell (Command prompt)